# Trying to convert into mysqli an "insert and update" query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert-update

I'm having this **MySQL** sentence which use an insert and update in the same query:

```
if(mysql_query('insert into forum_topics (parent, id, id2, title, message, authorid, timestamp, timestamp2) select "'.$dn1['parent'].'", "'.$id.'", max(id2)+1, "", "'.$message.'", "'.$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'].'", "'.time().'", "'.time().'" from forum_topics where id="'.$id.'"') and mysqli_query('update forum_topics set timestamp2="'.time().'" where id="'.$id.'" and id2=1'))
```

Which I tried to convert into **mysqli** this way:

```
$qry = 'insert into forum_topics (parent, id, id2, title, message, authorid, timestamp, timestamp2) select "'.$dn1['parent'].'", "'.$id.'", max(id2)+1, "", "'.$message.'", "'.$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'].'", "'.time().'", "'.time().'" from forum_topics where id="'.$id.'"';
$qry2 = 'update forum_topics set timestamp2="'.time().'" where id="'.$id.'" and id2=1';
$dn3 = $link -> query($qry AND $qry2);

if (!$dn3)...
```

Unfortunately, it don't seem to work as I'm being throwed this error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Is there anyone who can help with this?

Comment: Don't use string concatenation, use prepared statements.

Comment: Prepared statements are not designed to prevent sql injection, but to enable effective repeated execution of the same statement with different parameters. You can prevents sql injection even if string concatenation is used.

Comment: @Shadow: Actually they are also designed to prevent injections.

Comment: It's a side effect, not an intentional decision. If you do not issue the same statement repeatedly, then the use of prepared statements will reduce the efficiency of your code. Since mysql limits the number of prepared statements in the memory, irresponsible use may result in reaching that limit quite quickly, esspecially in free, shared hosting environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to follow the original logic, then

```
$dn3 = ($link -> query($qry) AND $link->query($qry2));
```

Because of the logical and operator in the php code, the 2 query strings were interpreted in a boolean operation BEFORE they were submitted to mysql.

As a result, the value 1 (true) was sent to mysql, which obviously resulted in the syntax error message.

Comment: It's not the queries that have an issue, it's the way the 2 queries are issued in the question that causes the problem.

Comment: String_variable1 and string_variable2 expression will yield 1 (true), and this is what is in the error message. So, I would revoke that -1 juergen. It's a pity sometimes that a comment cannot be downvoted...

Comment: The error message is from the DB. So the query is wrong here. And there the error must be fixed and not in the PHP code.

Comment: Thank you Shadow
This is exactly what i needed and therefor it now works.

Yes, i could use prepared statement but since i am not a guru coder, ill prefer to convert as simple as i can :)

+1 for shadow

Comment: @juergend Sorry man, but you have no idea what you are talking about! Because of the logical and operator in the php code, the 2 query strings were interpreted in a boolean operation BEFORE they were submitted to mysql. As a result, the value 1 (true) was sent to mysql, which obviously resulted in the syntax error message that was displayed in the question.